# PubNub subscribe with AuthKey error 403 in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, pubnub

I use PubNub chat, I enbale Access Manager and I subscribe a channel.
The Android SDK worked well, but I'm facing many issue with iOS SDK (Objective C)
 1. I couldn't set secrectKey (iOS has no function for this)
 2. I must use authKey solution

```
    PNConfiguration *config = [PNConfiguration configurationWithPublishKey:kPublishKey subscribeKey:kSubscribeKey];
    config.authKey = @"maftaf5dzfVcATrHQjMahUQlEb92UNZu";
    [config setUUID:self.UUID];
    [client subscribeToChannels: @[@"myglobalchannel"] withPresence:YES];
```

And I got error 403

```
{
Category = "Access Denied";
Error = YES;
Objects =     {
    Channels =         (
        "myglobalchannel",
        "myglobalchannel-pnpres"
    );
};
Operation = Subscribe;
Region =     {
    Current = "-1";
    Previous = "<empty>";
};
Request =     {
    Authorization = maftaf5dzfVcATrHQjMahUQlEb92UNZu;
    Method = GET;
    Origin = "ps.pndsn.com";
    "POST Body size" = 0;
    Secure = YES;
    URL = "https://ps.pndsn.com/v2/subscribe/sub-c-809672b6-2c40-11e8-8305-f27a6a4e1feb/myglobalchannel,myglobalchannel-pnpres/0?deviceid=4810A924-0CD4-4C1C-A239-3E2028895F0E&uuid=pn-450E2851-77DA-47F2-A95E-F7D053F36EFE&requestid=4BD7D461-2ABE-411D-96E7-6E4F80951C5A&pnsdk=PubNub-ObjC-iOS%2F4.7.7&tt=0&instanceid=0F979806-2011-4898-A708-E5672E725FAF&auth=maftaf5dzfVcATrHQjMahUQlEb92UNZu";
    UUID = "pn-450E2851-77DA-47F2-A95E-F7D053F36EFE";
};
Response =     {
    "Processed data" =         {
        channelGroups =             (
        );
        channels =             (
            "myglobalchannel-pnpres"
        );
        information = Forbidden;
    };
    "Status code" = 403;
};
Time =     {
    Current = 0;
    Previous = 0;
};
```

}

These codes worked well if I disable Asscee Manager and don't use authKey.
Give me advice, pls

Comment: Looks like your iOS SDK is subscribing to both `myglobalchannel` and `myglobalchannel-pnpres` channels.  Did you grant an `auth_key` **read** permissions on both channels?

Comment: You should never init PubNub with secret-key in your client applications. The secret-key gives the holder of that key all permissions to all channels and so you are exposing this key to the public by including it in your client apps. It should only be used in your secure server apps for the purpose of granting permissions on auth-keys that get used by your client apps.

Comment: @Stephen Blum: When subscribe [client subscribeToChannels: @[@"myglobalchannel"] withPresence:YES]; with presence = true, it automatic subscribe myglobalchannel-pnpres, it seem my trouble

Comment: Good find!  You can disable the presence channel.  If presence is disabled on your client then you will not need to grant access to that channel.

Comment: Or if you want to subscribe with presence with Access Manager, you have to grant read access to both the channel and it's -pnpres channel.